# How do I remove links from the Wordpress Twenty Twenty header?

Tags: wordpress

I'm brand-new to Wordpress. I'm using the Twenty Twenty theme, and the header has a bunch of links on the right-hand side that are the names of my posts and "Sample Page." I want to remove them.

From the Wordpress control panel, I've found the Appearance > Theme Editor page and pulled up the `header.php` file. I know very little PHP, but I don't see the links anywhere in this file, and I don't see a comment indicating what block creates the links.

How do I remove these links from the Twenty Twenty header?

Answer (score 0):

this may work:
Go to Appearance > Customize > General
Choose "Layout"
There you see multiple layouts. Choose a layout without the links.
Voila!

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  I have Appearance > Customize, but no "General," "Layout," "Header," or anything else I can find that affects these links, though.